# Flutter bottomsheet does not update view

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `Slider.adaptive` in bottomsheet but it does not update my view regardless that I am using `StatefulBuilder`.

Here is minimized version of my code:

```
Duration _duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 0);
Duration _position = const Duration(milliseconds: 0);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return PopScope(
    canPop: false,
    onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
      if (isPlaying == true) {
        setState(() async {
          await audioPlayer.stop();
        });
      }
    },
    child: Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Text('Testing Screen'),
        )
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        color: Colors.black,
        height: 130,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const FaIcon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.headphones,
                color: Colors.white70,
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                _openAudioBottomSheet();
              },
            ),
          ]
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

void  _openAudioBottomSheet() {
  showModalBottomSheet(
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20.0)),
      ),
      context: context,
      showDragHandle: true,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Slider.adaptive(
                      min: 0,
                      max: _duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                      value: _position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                      onChanged: (value) async {
                        debugPrint('value is:: $value');
                        setState(() {
                          _position = Duration(seconds: value.toInt());
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        );
      }
  );
}
```

**Any idea of how to make this view update works?**

## Update

I've noticed one thing just now, problem is most likely caused by `_position` data not passing to `showModalBottomSheet` rather than `onChanged` method issue!

It seems `_position` will not get updated duration in bottom sheet therefore slider doesn't move forward.

here is my audioplayer initialization code:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initAudioPlayer();
  }

  initAudioPlayer() async {
    audioPlayer.setAudioContext(
        const AudioContext(
          android: AudioContextAndroid(),
          iOS: AudioContextIOS(),
        )
    );

    audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((PlayerState event) {
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = event == PlayerState.playing;
        audioPlayer.setVolume(_volume);

        if (PlayerState == PlayerState.completed || PlayerState == PlayerState.stopped || PlayerState == PlayerState.paused) {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false; // Loading is complete
          });
        } else if (PlayerState == PlayerState.playing) {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = true; // Audio loading is in progress
          });
        }
      });
    });

    audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((Duration event) {
      setState(() {
        _duration = event;
      });
    });

    audioPlayer.onPositionChanged.listen((Duration event) {
      // this does get updated, but wont pass to bottomsheet!
      debugPrint('value is: $event');
      setState(() {
        _position = event;
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not updating because the `max` and `min` are same which is zero.

Another noticeable thing is, you have define millisecond on but using as second, have the same format will make it more readable.

---

```dart
  Duration _duration = const Duration(seconds: 1000);
  Duration _position = const Duration(seconds: 0);
  void _openAudioBottomSheet() async {
    await showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setStateSB) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Slider.adaptive(
                      min: 0,
                      max: _duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                      value: _position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                      onChanged: (value) async {
                        debugPrint('value is:: $value');
                        setStateSB(() {
                          _position = Duration(seconds: value.toInt());
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: I've noticed one thing just now, problem is most likely caused by `_position` data not passing to `showModalBottomSheet` rather than `onChanged` method issue! it seems `_position` will not get updated in bottom sheet therefore slider doesn't move

Comment: ok you can check the update

Comment: `The reason it is not updating because the max and min are same which is zero` 2 things here: 1- i don't see you providing different solution here (still its my code) 2- if I move same code to my `Widget build` slider moves just fine, whatever issue is. its related to `showModalBottomSheet`

Comment: I think problem is that `audioPlayer.onPositionChanged` value will not pass to `showModalBottomSheet`. `showModalBottomSheet` only gets `_position` value from when it was opened.

Comment: for 1>>  I did change the 1st line of code, if you run the demo, you will see the result and I didnt tested with audioPlayer. For last comment, you might like having ValueNotifier.

Comment: can't make `ValueListenableBuilder` for `_position.inSeconds.toDouble()`!

Answer (score 0):

using this one changed to Statefull Builder position and showBottomSheet instead of showModelBottomSheet

```
void  _openAudioBottomSheet() {
  showBottomSheet(
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20.0)),
      ),
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                StatefulBuilder(
                  builder: (context, setState) {
                    return Slider.adaptive(
                      min: 0,
                      max: _duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                      value: _position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                      onChanged: (value) async {
                        debugPrint('value is:: $value');
                        setState(() {
                          _position = Duration(seconds: value.toInt());
                        });
                      },
                    );
                  }
                )
              ]
            )
          )
        );
      }
  );
}
```

Comment: it says `No Scaffold widget found.`

Answer (score 0):

You are using an audio player library, and you've correctly identified that the issue might be related to _position not getting updated in the showModalBottomSheet. This could be due to the fact that the showModalBottomSheet creates a separate context for the bottom sheet, and the state might not be properly passed.

By passing _position as a parameter to _openAudioBottomSheet and using it as the initial value for the slider, you ensure that the correct position is set in the bottom sheet.

Comment: sorry what is changed in your code?

Comment: Duration _duration = const Duration(seconds: 10);

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with `showModalBottomSheet`, you cannot update a value in the main widget then expect the changes to be displayed right immediately in the bottom sheet. It typically requires you to open a new instance of the bottom sheet which I'm sure is something you don't want.

So my suggestion is to use a workaround by declaring an extra position variable but for the bottom sheet alone. It should be named differently from the main variable. Then when the position is changed by the user, you update both the position variables. One is a position variable for the local bottom sheet, while the other is for the main widget's. This ensures that, if the user closes the bottom sheet then opened it again, the value would remain consistent.

```
void  _openAudioBottomSheet() {
  showModalBottomSheet(
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20.0)),
      ),
      context: context,
      showDragHandle: true,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        Duration _localBottomSheetPosition = _position;
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Slider.adaptive(
                      min: 0,
                      max: _duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                      value: _localBottomSheetPosition.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                      onChanged: (value) async {
                        debugPrint('value is:: $value');
                        setState(() {
                          _localBottomSheetPosition = Duration(seconds: value.toInt());
                          _position = Duration(seconds: value.toInt());
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        );
      }
  );
}
```

Hope this solves your issue.